# Rsync using java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with double qoute in command

Tags: java, cmd, runtime, rsync, processbuilder

Hello I am trying to execute following :

```
Process p = null;
StringBuffer rbCmd = new StringBuffer();

rbCmd.append("rsync -e \"ssh -i /root/.ssh/key\" -va --relative /home/lego/hyb/abc/PVR2/Testdata/./R887/SCM/System root@myMachine:/xyz/data/SCMdata/");

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(rbCmd.toString());
```

But I am getting following error on command line.Command executes correctly on command line

Missing trailing-" in remote-shell command.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(361) [sender=3.0.6]

Issue is because of double quotes inside the command where I mention ssh key.

Please help with correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't work because `Runtime.exec()` does not realize that "ssh -i /root/.ssh/key" is a single argument to `rsync`. Escaping the double-quotes keeps the compiler happy, but doesn't remove the fundamental problem, which is the limits of the built-in tokenizer.

You might have more luck with something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
    (new String[]{"rsync", "-e", "ssh -i /root/.ssh/key", "-va" "--relative" ... });
```

That is, tokenize the command line yourself, and form the individual tokens into a `String[]`. You're deciding in advance what the arguments to `rsync` are, rather than allowing `exec()` to figure it out (wrongly).

Don't forget that if `rsync` produces any output, you'll need to arrange for your application to consume its `stdout` and `stderr`, or it could stall.